# How can I join two columns based on its position?

Tags: r

I have a data frame in which two of its columns are the following:

```
                 datos.dates_ev
1 2010-2012;2012-2013;2014-2015
2 2010-2012;2012-2013;2014-2015
3 2006-2008;2010-2012;2014-2015

  datos.ha_ev
1 3.96;10.08;3.60
2 7.83;12.24;3.06
3  3.87;4.23;0.81
```

I want to be able to manipulate each column as a new table, so then be able to use the first table as the header of the second table.

For example, I want to access to all the "area" that belong to the period "2010-2012" and summarize it.

What I exactly want to do is to separate both character columns into new tables where the first column contain the headers of the second column. And after all, I want to compute aggregates by the first column (dates_ev).

Below, I present the type of data for each column:

```
 'data.frame':  29785 obs. of  13 variables:
 $ OBJECTID  : int  1093 1095 1105 1107 1111 1115 1118 1126 1130 1142 ...
 $ id_group  : int  216 281 434 457 495 572 577 620 646 831 ...
 $ n_events  : int  3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 ...
 $ ini_date  : Factor w/ 11 levels "","2000-2002",..: 7 7 5 4 4 4 4 2 3 3 ...
 $ end_date  : Factor w/ 11 levels "","2002-2004",..: 9 9 9 6 6 5 8 5 5 8 ...
 $ ini_ha    : num  3.96 7.83 3.87 8.19 6.12 0.27 2.52 0.72 1.08 2.16 ...
 $ end_ha    : num  17.64 23.13 8.91 23.94 10.08 ...
 $ n_fids    : int  8 13 8 9 9 5 8 4 4 18 ...
 $ fids      : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ dates_ev  : Factor w/ 1962 levels "","2000-2002;2002-2004",..: 1915 1915 1805 1598 1535 1471 1673 377 1222 1393 ...
 $ ha_ev     : Factor w/ 60888 levels "","0.09;0.09",..: 48590 58608 48335 59113 55724 3322 39314 9977 18755 36365 ...
 $ SHAPE_Leng: num  6000 6780 3480 5520 2580 ...
 $ SHAPE_Area: num  176400 231300 89100 239400 100800 ...
```

Comment: Daniel, please include your expected output.

Comment: It’s not clear what you really want. Please give us more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not very clear what you're trying to do. I assume you want to "un-nest" semicolon-separated entries in both columns.

Here is a `tidyverse` option

```
library(tidyverse)
df.long <- df %>%
    mutate_all(~str_split(.x, ";")) %>%
    unnest()
df.long
#  datos.dates_ev datos.ha_ev
#1      2010-2012        3.96
#2      2012-2013       10.08
#3      2014-2015        3.60
#4      2010-2012        7.83
#5      2012-2013       12.24
#6      2014-2015        3.06
#7      2006-2008        3.87
#8      2010-2012        4.23
#9      2014-2015        0.81
```

You can then use `filter` to select a subset of entries; e.g. to select entries from the period `2010-2012` you would do

```
df.long %>% filter(datos.dates_ev == "2010-2012")
#  datos.dates_ev datos.ha_ev
#1      2010-2012        3.96
#2      2010-2012        7.83
#3      2010-2012        4.23
```

---

### Sample data

```
df <- read.table(text =
    "           datos.dates_ev        datos.ha_ev
1 2010-2012;2012-2013;2014-2015    3.96;10.08;3.60
2 2010-2012;2012-2013;2014-2015    7.83;12.24;3.06
3 2006-2008;2010-2012;2014-2015    3.87;4.23;0.81")
```

Answer (score 0):

Create one table by combining dates and ha as columns. As format was not specified here, probably you have to split string into element by ";". If it is already imported into R with proper format you can skip data manipulation before combining columns. Then reference as in data frame by condition to corresponding column

```
datos.dates_ev <- c("
2010-2012;2012-2013;2014-2015
2010-2012;2012-2013;2014-2015
2006-2008;2010-2012;2014-2015")

    datos.ha_ev <-  c("
3.96;10.08;3.60
7.83;12.24;3.06
3.87;4.23;0.81")

    datos.dates_ev <- str_split(gsub("\n", ";", datos.dates_ev), ";")
    datos.ha_ev <- str_split(gsub("\n", ";", datos.ha_ev), ";")

    datos <- cbind(as.data.frame(datos.dates_ev), as.data.frame(datos.ha_ev))
    colnames(datos) <- c("dates", "ha")
    datos[datos$dates=="2014-2015",]
```

Answer (score 0):

According to OP's description there is a dataframe which contains the two character columns `datos.dates_ev` and `datos.ha_ev`.

If I understand correctly, the OP wants to separate both character columns into new tables whereby `datos.dates_ev` contain the headers of `datos.ha_ev`. Finally, he wants to compute aggregates by `datos.dates_ev`.

```
# dataframe
datos <- structure(list(
  datos.dates_ev = c("2010-2012;2012-2013;2014-2015", "2010-2012;2012-2013;2014-2015", 
                     "2006-2008;2010-2012;2014-2015"), 
  datos.ha_ev = c("3.96;10.08;3.60", "7.83;12.24;3.06", "3.87;4.23;0.81")), 
  class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Split both columns into substrings and reshape into long format, thereby coercing `datos.ha_ev` from string to numeric for later computations:

```
library(data.table)
long <- setDT(datos)[
  , unlist(lapply(.SD, stringr::str_split, ";"), recursive = FALSE), 
  by = .(rn = 1:nrow(datos))][
    , datos.ha_ev := as.numeric(datos.ha_ev)]
long[]
```

> ```
>    rn datos.dates_ev datos.ha_ev
> 1:  1      2010-2012        3.96
> 2:  1      2012-2013       10.08
> 3:  1      2014-2015        3.60
> 4:  2      2010-2012        7.83
> 5:  2      2012-2013       12.24
> 6:  2      2014-2015        3.06
> 7:  3      2006-2008        3.87
> 8:  3      2010-2012        4.23
> 9:  3      2014-2015        0.81
> ```

---

**EDIT:**
Note that `strsplit()` will split only character arguments and throws an error otherwise. Now, the OP has disclosed that the production dataset contains factor variables instead of character. Therefore,  `strsplit()` has been replaced by `stringr::str_split()` which splits also factor variables.

The base R equivalent `function(x) strsplit(as.character(x), ";")` requires more typing.

---

The long form is very suitable for further data manipulations.

Reshaping to wide format:

```
dcast(long, rn ~ datos.dates_ev)
```

> ```
>    rn 2006-2008 2010-2012 2012-2013 2014-2015
> 1:  1        NA      3.96     10.08      3.60
> 2:  2        NA      7.83     12.24      3.06
> 3:  3      3.87      4.23        NA      0.81
> ```

Grouping and aggregating in different ways:

```
long[, sum(datos.ha_ev), by = datos.dates_ev]
```

> ```
>    datos.dates_ev    V1
> 1:      2010-2012 16.02
> 2:      2012-2013 22.32
> 3:      2014-2015  7.47
> 4:      2006-2008  3.87
> ```

or in wide format:

```
dcast(long, . ~ datos.dates_ev, sum)
```

> ```
>    . 2006-2008 2010-2012 2012-2013 2014-2015
> 1: .      3.87     16.02     22.32      7.47
> ```

Comment: Your solution is exactly what I wanted to do. However, I'm getting the following error: "Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : non-character argument", just when run the long line.

Comment: Perhaps, this is due to factor instead of character. Please, can you check what `str(datos)` shows for both columns?

Comment: I've edited the main post, showing the str for all the data, the variables that I'm using for the example are: "dates_ev" and "ha_ev".

Comment: @DanielGuerrero, Thanks for updating your post. I have replaced `strsplit()` by `stringr::str_split()` which takes also factor variables while `strsplit()` throws an error.